# Angular template dynamic property biding using loop

Tags: angular

What i want is to bind element property dynamically.
Properties should be binded based on the length of a given arr.

```
// arr.length = 0
const arr = []
// result
<div>
</div>

// arr.length = 3
const arr = ['name', 'age', 'sex']
// result
<div
  [attr.data-name]='varName'
  [attr.data-age]='varAge'
  [attr.data-sex]='varSex'
>
</div>

// arr.length = 4
const arr = ['name', 'age', 'sex', 'email']
// result
<div
  [attr.data-name]='varName'
  [attr.data-age]='varAge'
  [attr.data-sex]='varSex'
  [attr.email]='varEmail'
>
</div>
```

Is there a trick to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna set a `attribute` and for each property a own then you need to use the DOM directly.

So you can use ViewChild / ViewChildren.

**Code**

```
@ViewChild('child') child: any;

.....

ngAfterViewInit() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {  
    this.child.nativeElement.setAttribute("name-" + i.toString() , "dynamicAttrString");
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- A simple div with text-center as example-->
<div #child text-center>Testchild</div>
```

Important is to use ViewChild/ViewChildrens element first on `ngAfterViewInit`. It will be null on init or in constructor.

Component looks like that in the dev tools:
[image]